# Why is MongoDB using scanAndOrder here?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am saving games documents in MongoDB. Among other things the documents contain the name of the player (name), the time when the game has ended (endMS) and the type of the game (type). Type can have one out of five different values.

I need to search for all finished games by a player sorted by the time when the game has ended and for all finished games by a player with a certain game type also sorted by the time of the game end.

Examples for both queries are

> db.games.find({name:"Stefan",endMS:{$gt:0}}).sort({endMS:-1})

and

> db.games.find({name:"Stefan",type:"bli",endMS:{$gt:0}}).sort({endMS:-1})

You can use the indexes

> db.games.ensureIndex({name:1,endMS:-1})

and

> db.games.ensureIndex({name:1,type:1,endMS:-1})

for fast access.

Now I am trying to get along with just one index:

> db.games.ensureIndex({name:1,endMS:-1,type:1})

The first query or course still runs fine. The idea for the second query is that Mongo might need to skip some entries when scanning the index but only need to access the documents that are finally returned by the query because the "type" can already be checked in the index. That should be fast enough for my needs.

However using explain() MongoDB tells me that "scanAndOrder" is needed when querying the database like this.

> db.games.find({name:"Stefan",type:"bli",endMS:{$gt:0}}).sort({endMS:-1}).explain()

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name_1_endMS_-1_type_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 22,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 25,
    "scanAndOrder" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "name" : [
            [
                "Stefan",
                "Stefan"
            ]
        ],
        "endMS" : [
            [
                Infinity,
                0
            ]
        ],
        "type" : [
            [
                "bli",
                "bli"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "localhost:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

nscannedObjects and nscanned are as expected like described above, but I am wondering why Mongo says scanAndOrder:true.

According to the docs:
"scanAndOrder is a boolean that is true when the query cannot use the order of documents in the index for returning sorted results: MongoDB must sort the documents after it receives the documents from a cursor."

As far as I have understood it the documents should be ordered in the index, only some need to be skipped which doesn't affect the order.

So why is MongoDB using scanAndOrder here?

Comment: Which version of MongoDB are you using? It's strange that you have a true "scanAndOrder" and a false "indexOnly". I would say your query is index covered ...

Comment: I am using MongoDB 2.6.0-rc0. The search cannot be indexOnly because it returns the whole document. It is only "indexOnly" in the sense that it doesn't need to scan the document to find out if it matches the query.

Comment: Strange, I have added {_id:0,name:1} as the projection parameter to the query and this also won't make the query indexOnly. It might have something to do that "type" is actually "tc.type", so it is taken from an embedded document (I just wanted to make the issue clearer here). I remember that there is an issue in MongoDB's aggregation framework with coveredIndexes when when one part of the index comes from an embedded document. But does this also affect scanAndOrder?

Comment: I have done some more tests and it seems that index entry taken from an embedded document is not the problem here.

Comment: I would test it with a 2.4 version. If it is a bug you should [check this](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/77404624435/announcing-the-mongodb-bug-hunt-2-6-0-rc0)

Comment: Wow, I have tried 2.4.9 and scanAndOrder is suddenly false and with the projection parameter the search also gets indexOnly. So this seems to be a bug in 2.6.0-rc0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in MongoDB 2.6.0-rc0. All works as expected in MongoDB 2.4.9.

Answer (score 0):

Stefan reported the issue here: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12935 and the scanAndOrder issue was resolved after 2.6.0-rc0, but there are some lingering issues with the explain output.

Answer (score -2):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/

natural order:
The order that a database stores documents on disk. Typically, the order of documents on disks reflects insertion order, except when a document moves internally because an update operation increases its size. In capped collections, insertion order and natural order are identical because documents do not move internally. MongoDB returns documents in forward natural order for a find() query with no parameters. MongoDB returns documents in reverse natural order for a find() query sorted with a parameter of $natural:-1. See $natural.

Your assumption of insertion order == indexing order is wrong.

Comment: This is not my assumption. I assume that the docs are ordered by endMS because endMS is the second part of the compound index.

Comment: There you go, you answered your question. It's a bug :).  I have always use sort if I expect a certain order just to be sure, and optimize other areas if performance is not up to par.